# I accidentally performed a "git fetch" and now I can't execute "flutter update

Tags: flutter, git, dart, github

When I run `flutter upgrade`

```
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/my_user_name/flutter.git/' not found
  Command: git fetch --tags
```

An error message is displayed that says, "This is because I previously mistakenly performed a git fetch on Flutter from the local repository, and I believe that's the cause. I lack knowledge about Git, so I don't know how to resolve this issue. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to reset the remote repository URL back to the official Flutter repository.

Open CMD.

Navigate to your Flutter installation directory. where you cloned the Flutter. It might be something like ~/flutter or C:\src\flutter.

Run `git remote -v`
If you see any issue, reset it back to the official Flutter repository by:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
```

Now run `flutter upgrade`

Comment: Thank you for answering.
When I run the command as instructed, I get an error `error: No such remote 'origin'`.

Comment: @sub Ashikul suggested you run `git remote -v` before the set-url, it would output all available remotes. Did you do it? What did it output?

Comment: You will see the text `origin`

Comment: The path to execute the command was wrong.
I was able to solve the problem with the command you gave me. thank you.